# Trying to transform over-complicated array of objects in JSON using JQ

Tags: json, jq, data-cleaning

I've got a JSON document that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "My Team",
  "team size": [
    {
      "min": [
        {
          "Leader": 1
        },
        {
          "Followers": 5
        },
        {
          "point cost": 7
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "max": [
        {
          "Leader": 1
        },
        {
          "Followers": 9
        },
        {
          "point cost": 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
{
    "name": "My Team",
    "team size": [
        {
            "size": "min",
            "Leader": 1,
            "Followers": 5,
            "point cost": 7
        },
        {
            "size": "max",
            "Leader": 1,
            "Followers": 9,
            "point cost": 11
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm having a hard time with it. I know it's something like `jq . '"team size" |= map(to_entries[] | .key + .values)`, but I'm not getting the syntax right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one of many ways:

```
.["team size"] |=
  (add
   | [ ({size: "min"} + (.min | add)),
       ({size: "max"} + (.max | add)) ] )
```

or more DRYly:

```
.["team size"] |=
  (add
   | . as $in
   | reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k ([];
       . + [{size: $k} + ($in[$k]|add) ] ))
```